# 末尾の / (スラッシュ) の有無でリダイレクト先が異なってしまう

Tags: .htaccess

`.htaccess` に記載することでリダイレクトをさせようとしております。
ディレクトリ構成としては以下のようになっており、URLを `/site/aaaa` や `/site/bbbb` とすればアクセスできる状態です。

```
site
  └── aaaaディレクトリ
  └── bbbbディレクトリ
```

#### やりたいこと

- `site` 以下をドキュメントルートとし、URLを `/aaaa` と `/bbbb` としてもアクセスできる状態にしたい
- `/` にアクセスした場合も `/aaaa` にアクセスできる状態にしたい

以下のように記述すると、

- `/aaaa/` や `/` の場合は `/aaaa/` にちゃんと遷移する
- ただ、`/aaaa` とすると `/site/aaaa/` に遷移する

となっており、困っております。どちら様かご教示いただけないでしょうか。

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^$ aaaa/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/$1 [L]
```

なお、conoha Wingを利用しており、httpd.confでドキュメントルートを指定することはできなかった認識です。
上記のように仮に他のやり方の方がいい、ということがあれば、そちらのアドバイスもいただけると幸いです。
初心者の質問で恐縮ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

最後の RewriteRule で変換(/aaaa → /site/aaaa)した後、trailing slash を付けるためにリダイレクトされるのでしょう。
その前に trailing slash を付けるルール(/aaaa → /aaaa/)を挿入するといいと思います。

```
RewriteRule ^$ aaaa/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(aaaa|bbbb)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Taichi Yanagiyaさん、ありがとうございます！！ trailing slash を付けるルールを挿入、という発想はなかったです！とても勉強になりました！無事にご教示いただいた方法でうまくいくことができました！一人で数時間考えていたので救われました！！本当にありがとうございました！！